# How can I add some html to the beginning of a table cell (td)?

Tags: jquery, append, selector

I have a jquery select that represents a table cell

```
 <table>
    <tr><td class="cellClass">10</td></tr>
  </table>
```

what is the correct jquery syntax to add some html (in my case an image) at the beginning of the cell so it would end up like this:

```
 <table>
    <tr><td class="cellClass"><img src="/myimage.png" />10</td></tr>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`prepend`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) method:

```
$('.cellClass').prepend('<img src="/myimage.png" />')
```